# Unwrap value from Monad state context and concatenate two state contexts

Tags: parsing, haskell, functional-programming, monads

I am trying to write an `eval` function for my simple imperative language parser, but I'm facing some problems when I write it using **Control.Monad** and **State**.

At `evalComm`s **Let case** I need to unwrap type (**m Int**) to pass just **Int** to update function, is there a way to do it?

Also at `evalComm`s **Seq case** , I need to concatenate two evalComm functions for when the recursion opens in two ways. is `liftM` an alternative for this case?

```
type Env = [(Variable,Int)]

initState :: Env
initState = []

newtype State a = State { runState :: Env -> (a, Env) }

instance Monad State where
    return x = State (\s -> (x, s))
    m >>= f = State (\s -> let (v, s') = runState m s in
                           runState (f v) s')

instance Functor State where
    fmap = liftM

instance Applicative State where
    pure   = return
    (<*>)  = ap      

class Monad m => MonadState m where
    lookfor :: Variable -> m Int
    update :: Variable -> Int -> m ()

instance MonadState State where
    lookfor v = State (\s -> (lookfor' v s, s))
                where lookfor' v ((u, j):ss) | v == u = j
                                             | v /= u = lookfor' v ss
    update v i = State (\s -> ((), update' v i s))
                 where update' v i [] = [(v, i)]
                       update' v i ((u, _):ss) | v == u = (v, i):ss
                       update' v i ((u, j):ss) | v /= u = (u, j):(update' v i ss)

eval :: Comm -> Env
eval p = snd (runState (evalComm p) initState)

evalComm :: MonadState m => Comm -> m ()
evalComm c = case c of
                  Skip          -> return ()
                  Let v i       -> update v (evalIntExp i)
                  Seq c1 c2     -> return (liftM2 (:) (evalComm c2) (evalComm c1))

evalIntExp :: MonadState m => IntExp -> m Int
evalIntExp v = case v of
                    Const x             -> return (fromInteger x)
                    Var x               -> lookfor x
                    UMinus x            -> liftM (*(-1)) (evalIntExp x)
                    Plus x y            -> liftM2 (+) (evalIntExp x) (evalIntExp y)
                    Minus x y           -> liftM2 (-) (evalIntExp x) (evalIntExp y)
                    Times x y           -> liftM2 (*) (evalIntExp x) (evalIntExp y)
                    Div x y             -> liftM2 div (evalIntExp x) (evalIntExp y)


evalBoolExp :: MonadState m => BoolExp -> m Bool
evalBoolExp b = case b of
                     BTrue        -> return True
                     BFalse       -> return False
                     Eq x y       -> liftM2 (==) (evalIntExp x) (evalIntExp y)
                     Lt x y       -> liftM2 (<) (evalIntExp x) (evalIntExp y)
                     Gt x y       -> liftM2 (>) (evalIntExp x) (evalIntExp y)
                     And b0 b1    -> liftM2 (&&) (evalBoolExp b0) (evalBoolExp b1)
                     Or b0 b1     -> liftM2 (||) (evalBoolExp b0) (evalBoolExp b1)
                     Not b        -> liftM not (evalBoolExp b)
```

Note that the code for evalComm is not working and it may be incorrect.

Here is my Abstract Syntax tree:

```
type Variable = String

data IntExp = Const Integer
            | Var Variable
            | UMinus IntExp
            | Plus IntExp IntExp
            | Minus IntExp IntExp
            | Times IntExp IntExp
            | Div IntExp IntExp
            | Quest BoolExp IntExp IntExp
 deriving Show

data BoolExp = BTrue
             | BFalse
             | Eq IntExp IntExp
             | Lt IntExp IntExp
             | Gt IntExp IntExp
             | And BoolExp BoolExp
             | Or BoolExp BoolExp
             | Not BoolExp
 deriving Show

data Comm = Skip
          | Let Variable IntExp
          | Seq Comm Comm
          | Cond BoolExp Comm Comm
          | While BoolExp Comm
          | Repeat Comm BoolExp
 deriving Show
```

Comment: I'm still pretty much a beginner with Haskell so I don't fully follow your code - but with regards to "I need to unwrap type (m Int) to pass just Int to update function, is there a way to do it?", is this exactly what the monadic "bind" operator (`>>=`) isn't designed to do?

Comment: @RobinZigmond I tried using it but I could not make it work! I’ll try again. If you can provide an example, or if someone else can, it would be great

Comment: @victor.ja `(>>=)` is definitely the right tool for this job, so please show what you tried and the error you got.

Comment: does this: `return (liftM2 (:) (evalComm c2) (evalComm c1))` compile?. `evalComm c1` is not a `list`, is `m ()` instead.

Comment: @LuisMorillo no, it doesn’t. I clarified that evalComm it’s wrong. Maybe I can put it in bold, because it’s at the middle of the question!

Comment: @victor.ja Sorry, I read It but I thought you meant that "Is not working _as expected_", not that it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The Let case

As Zigmond and Wagner said, `(>>=)` is the right tool for the job. Let's look at the types:

```
(>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
update :: Variable -> Int -> m ()
evalIntExp i :: m Int
v :: Variable
```

Can you think of a way to combine these into the expected type `m ()`? Remember that you can apply a function partially to get back a function that takes fewer arguments.

#### The Seq case

Let's look at the types again.

We have two values of type `m ()`, (`evalComm c1` and `evalComm c2`) and want to combine them into a value of type `m ()`. We can use `>>=` again by creating a function that ignores its argument:

```
Seq c1 c2  -> (evalComm c1) >>= (\x -> (evalComm c1))
```

However, this is such a common scenario so there is already a builtin function for this:

```
(>>) :: m a -> m b -> m b

Seq c1 c2  -> evalComm c1 >> evalComm c1
```

---

Let's look at your previous code

```
liftM2 (:) :: m a -> m [a] -> m [a]
```

You don't have lists so this is not useful.

```
liftM2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> m a -> m b -> m c
```

This can be used if `a = b = c = ()`, but it is needlessly complicated compared to just using `>>`. However, I encourage you to try it as an exercise. How would a function of type `() -> () -> ()` look?

```
return :: a -> m a
```

This is used when you have a pure value and need to convert it into a monadic value, so no need to use it here. The result would have the double-wrapped type `m (m ())` which is not what you want.

#### Final words

As you can see, the types can be very helpful when writing Haskell programs. Whenever you wonder what things can be combined, look at the types. You can check out what type an expression has by typing `:t <expression>` in GHCi.

Answer (score 2):

Two things.

First, I think your update function is wrong, since you are pattern match the same thing twice. Why not?:

```
update v i = State (\s -> ((), update' v i s))
             where update' v i [] = [(v, i)]
                   update' v i ((u, j):ss) | v == u = (v, i):ss
                                           | v /= u = (u, j):(update' v i ss)
```

This update function is creating a list of pairs. As @Hjulle posted, using the `>>` operator will do: *compute first result, then compute the second*. In this case, computing a result using `evalComm` is ultimately *update the state or return `()`*. So your code should be something like:

```
evalComm :: MonadState m => Comm -> m ()
evalComm c = case c of
                  Skip          -> return ()
                  Let v i       -> evalIntExp i >>= \o -> update v o
                  Seq c1 c2     -> evalComm c1 >> evalComm c2
```

`evalIntExp i >>= \o -> update v o` means: *compute `evalIntExp i`, take the resulting `Int` a pass it to the `update` function*

This implementation returns:

```
let exp1 = Seq (Seq (Let "string1" (Const 1)) (Let "string2" (Const 2))) Skip 

> eval exp1
[("string1",1),("string2",2)]
```

But fails in other examples.